# running another script inside of php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have been using a php script to call the contents of an ordinary html file and display the contents like so:

```
echo file_get_contents('./login.html');
```

this has worked fine for a long time.  however, login.html now needs to become a php script.

so, i need to have the php 'parent' script internally redirect to a php 'child' script, but retain the parent script name in the url.

i have tried the following so far:

1 - [using "header":](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715792/can-i-redirect-to-an-internal-link-using-php)

`header('Location: http://mydomain(dot)com/login.php');`

this replaces the parent URL with the login script url which is unacceptable.

2 - [window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689471/alternative-to-header-for-re-directs-in-php)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.location.href='http://mydomain(dot)com/login.php';
</script>
```

same problem as #1 - the parent URL is getting replaced.

3 - [jquery load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433319/embed-an-external-page-without-an-iframe)

```
$('#loginPage').load('http://mydomain(dot)com/login.php');
```

very close, but some of the jquery/css is getting lost along the way

4 - [using iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710039/full-page-iframe)

```
<iframe frameborder='0' width='100%' height='100%' src= 'http://mydomain(dot)com/login.php'></iframe>
```

this actually displays properly, but window.location.href now contains the name of the child script, not the parent script.

i am sure there is a way to do this with minimal code.  please let me know if this question is clear enough.

any suggestions?

---

edit:

my login.php page still needs to be able to be referenced as a stand-alone page as before.

Comment: The file extension of *login.html* is HTML so any PHP within that file will not be executed.You'll need to change the file extension for the *login* file.

Comment: And you can't [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) it either?

Comment: i cannot include it since login.php needs to be a standalone script as well as an embedded one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is include: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
rename your html script to login.php then just use

```
include('./login.php');
```

where you want to in your main php script.

I am not sure what you are trying to do with your tests, in some cases 1,2 you are taking them to a new page, in others 3,4 you are embedding it in your page.

Comment: beat me to it :) up'd.

Comment: hmm well i may have to rewrite login.php to run as an "include" rather than a stand-alone program.   my big iFrame idea did not work so it turns out.

Comment: why not just rename it to php, and change what you need in it?

Comment: ok this basically worked, but i had to move much of the php code from the child to the parent to keep the css/jscript working.   thank you.